# How to change the template file(s) for an existing nx schematic

Tags: reactjs, redux, monorepo, nrwl, nomachine-nx

I started to use https://nx.dev/ recently to reorganize an existing monorepo with multiple react frontends and redux state management.

nx provides the ability to create new redux slices out of the box using the `@nrwl/react:redux` schematic like: `nx g @nrwl/react:redux <sliceName>`. This is great! However, the template that is being used to create new files does not fit my needs (for example I do not use redux-thunk...) and I would like to use my own template.

I created a new custom schematic with `nx g workspace-schematic redux-module` and adjusted it to extend `@nrwl/react:redux` like:

```
import { chain, externalSchematic, Rule } from '@angular-devkit/schematics';

export default function(schema: any): Rule {
  return chain([
    externalSchematic('@nrwl/react', 'redux', {
      name: schema.name
    })
  ]);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to proceed from here to make the custom schematic use my own template files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have the template files inside the directory, load them and then copy to the target destination.e.g.

**Dir structure:**

```
Project_root
|- tools
   |- schematics
      |- your_schematics
         |- index.ts  
         |- templates
            |- __name@dasherize__.custom.ts
```

**Content:**

```
/* __name@dasherize__.custom.ts */

export class <%= classify(name) %>Custom {
    constructor () {}
}

/* index.ts */

import { chain, externalSchematic, Rule, url, apply, move, mergeWith, MergeStrategy, template, SchematicContext } from '@angular-devkit/schematics';
import { dasherize, classify } from '@angular-devkit/core/src/utils/strings';
import { normalize, strings } from '@angular-devkit/core';


export default function(schema: any): Rule {
  const libFileName = dasherize(schema.name);
  const projectDirectory = schema.directory
    ? normalize(schema.directory + '/' + libFileName)
    : libFileName;
  const projectRoot = normalize('libs/' + projectDirectory);

  return chain([
     externalSchematic('@nrwl/workspace', 'lib', schema),
     addCustomFileToLib(schema, projectRoot)
  ]);
}

function addCustomFileToLib(schema: any, projectRoot: string): Rule {
  const templateFiles = url("./templates");
  const newTree = apply(templateFiles, [
    move(projectRoot),
    template({
      ...strings,
      ...schema // pass the objects containing the properties & functions to be used in template file
    })
  ]);
  return mergeWith(newTree, MergeStrategy.Default);
}
```

Note: Name of template file(`__name@dasherize__.custom.ts`) is an expression which will be compiled/changed according to the *name* arg passed from cli while executing the schematics.

Comment: thanks! I will give it a try and report back. bit busy with other things at the moment unfortunately...